# Animation running while app is paused

Tags: android, android-animation

It is possible to have Android Animations running even when the app Activity gets `onPause()`, for instance if the user switches to another app, or pushes the Home button, or the power button?

It is a strict requirement from someone asking me to write an app and a bit complicated to explain here. It seems my experimental apps are put on hold completely, and especially animations are completely paused. Then they resume perfectly when the app resumes, but it's not good enough for this one app.

Comment: What are you using to animate?

Comment: Currently ViewFlipper and two XML files defining the in and out animations. (The specific animation might change, currently it is just fade in/out). If there's another way, I change it.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are trying to flip a view using xml animations? Can you post more details about what are you doing? Doing it while the background is not recommended though

Comment: The animation works perfectly as it is. I just need it to continue also in pause mode - I am aware that doing it in the background is not recommended but this is a very special case.